# Timed C++ Program Trouble

Tags: c++, time, xcode5

I am making a typing speed test program that has a loop that needs to run for 60 seconds then exit out and display the results.  I have read other places about timing a C++ program, but my research has turned up inconclusive.  The program is turning up (llbd) and I was hoping that someone would have a solution/better way to solve this problem.  Also, Xcode is the only software available for me right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

string words[100];
string answer;
int rand_word = 0;
int speed = 0;
int wrong = 0;
int loop = 0;
clock_t t1;

void void_word();

int main(){

    char pause;
    cout << "Typing Speed Test" << endl;
    cout << "Press any Key to Continue";
    cin >> pause;
    t1 = clock();
    {
       if((t1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) == 60){
           loop = 1;
       }
       void_word();
       cout << words[rand_word];
       cin >> answer;
       if(answer == words[rand_word]){
           speed ++;
       }
       if(answer != words[rand_word]){
           wrong ++;
       }
       srand (time(NULL)); // don't understand why underlined?
    }while (loop == 1)

    cout << "Your typing speed was " << speed << "WPM - with " << wrong << " wrong words" << endl;
    return 0;
}
void void_word(){
    rand_word = rand() % 40 + 1; // will change to ~ 100

    words[1] = "the";
    words[2] = "be";
    words[3] = "and";
    words[4] = "woman";
    words[5] = "good";
    words[6] = "through";
    words[7] = "child";
    words[8] = "there";
    words[9] = "those";
    words[10] = "work";
    words[11] = "should";
    words[12] = "world";
    words[13] = "after";
    words[14] = "country";
    words[15] = "pattern";
    words[16] = "it";
    words[17] = "enough";
    words[18] = "read";
    words[19] = "sit";
    words[20] = "right";
    words[21] = "tail";
    words[22] = "deep";
    words[23] = "dark";
    words[24] = "first";
    words[25] = "self";
    words[26] = "their";
    words[27] = "free";
    words[28] = "hundred";
    words[29] = "group";
    words[30] = "car";
    words[31] = "did";
    words[32] = "self";
    words[33] = "best";
    words[34] = "snow";
    words[35] = "language";
    words[36] = "pound";
    words[37] = "early";
    words[38] = "call";
    words[39] = "boat";
    words[40] = "light";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you programming for? If you are on Windows, use `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter`. If your are  on Linux, use `<chrono>`

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah The question is flagged with `xcode5` so I guess it is Mac OS related.

Comment: @Chnossos Ahh yeah sorry I'm not too familiar with non-microsoft software :S ...

Comment: I am using Mac OS with Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the points raised by @MrZebra, I want to say:

Using `clock` is not appropriate. It measures processor clock used by the program. It does not measure real time. You should use `time`. The main loop can be changed to:

```
time_t start;
time(&start);
do
{
   time_t now;
   time(&now);
   if(difftime(now, start) > 60)
   {
       break;
   }
   rand_word = rand() % 40 + 1; // will change to ~ 100
   cout << words[rand_word] << " " << flush;
   cin >> answer;
   if(answer == words[rand_word]){
       speed ++;
   }
   if(answer != words[rand_word]){
       wrong ++;
   }
}while (true);
```

Comment: Thank you R Sahu and @MrZebra, my program is now working perfectly and am going to use your advice in future programs.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what your question is, so here are a few pointers to help you on your way.

You are missing the `do` for your while loop - the part that actually loops will be the `cout` on the line after.

You shouldn't call `srand()` in a loop.  If your loop is fast then `time()` will return the same value multiple times, which will cause `srand()` to keep seeding the random number generator with the same value, which in turn will make `rand()` keep returning the same value.

You should also check if the time is `> 60` not `==`, as if the user takes more than one second to type the word it could miss the 60th second.

You also don't need to initialize the word list every time around the loop, and arrays in C start at zero not one.

Using global variables for everything is unnecessary and not good practice, you should declare your variables inside the function where they are used where possible.

Comment: To add to your good suggestions, I would also want to point out that instead of using C-style srand()/rand() with modulo to get a number in a random number in a range, I would encourage to use std::random_device, std::default_random_engine and std::uniform_int_distribution. While overkill in a sense, I'd say it's a much better habit to use them instead of old C-api, if you are doing C++.